# QGIS Line intersetction using WMS layer - wrong intersection points

Tags: qgis, line, intersection

I'm trying to identify intersections between multiples lines but I'm kind of getting weird results..
Please check the image below (WMS layer in blue).

[image: Red=wrong interstion points | Yellow=should have been identified by the software as an intersection]

Below the settings I'm using:
[image]

What settings should I use to get the correct results?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what does the WMS layer show? where is it from? how does it relate to the intersection?

Comment: Well, this WMS layer shows the water lines in Portugal mainland as you can see here: 
image link: https://i.ibb.co/NgBh0mY/bacia.png

The goal is to identify the intersection points where the WMS layer crosses the layer with roads, to point out possible bridges.

I tried to convert the raster WMS to vector using the appropriate function in QGIS menu, but it gives an error.

Official agency, supplies an WFS option, but it displays weirdly on canvas. Check the available links on top: https://sniambgeoogc.apambiente.pt/getogc/rest/services/SNIAmb/MA_BaciasHidrograficas_PtCont/MapServer

Comment: Correct link: https://sniambgeoogc.apambiente.pt/getogc/rest/services/SNIAmb/RdHidrografica_GeoCodificada/MapServer

and I would like to thank you for the reply

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.